# Is it possible to force ActiveRecord's #saved_change_to_attribute? method to equal true when the object is being updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm writing a microservice (Service A) that relies heavily on one of the other services (Service B). Service B is a Ruby on Rails application. Both Service A and Service B share a db. Service A receives a request and updates a table in the db. When Service B receives that same request, it uses ActiveRecord and a lot of callbacks on the AR model. Rather than spreading the same business logic between services, I'd like to event that request to Service B. This way, Service B can "update" the model (the word "update" is in parentheses because the services share the same db and the record is already updated) and trigger all of the callbacks.

For example, assume a request is made to Service A to update the name of a user. Service A updates the user's name in the db, and then events this change to Service B. Service B receives the request and does something similar to the following:

```rb
user = User.find(id: user_id)

user.update_attribue(:name, name)
```

This triggers ActiveRecord callbacks on the `User` model. In one of the callbacks, the following conditional statement is made: `saved_change_to_name?`. This returns `false` because the record wasn't actually updated since Service A already updated the db.

Is it possible to force this change and have `saved_change_to_name?` result in true?
For example:

```rb
user = User.find(id: user_id)

user.force_update_attribue(:name, name)
```

Service A still needs to update the db because we're moving towards an approach where each service has its own data store. Removing the conditional is also not an option here.

Comment: Using force update will cost you additional write operations which is not efficient. So if you cannot remove the condition, you can update it to check if the field that is to be updated already has the provided value in it. e.g `user.saved_change_to_name? || user.try(:name) == name`

Comment: This really begs the question if the callback itself is the problem.

Comment: Yes, the callback is the problem. What I found to be the best solution for us was to pull out the business logic from the callback into a callable method. ActiveRecord doesn't support "forced updates" like I mentioned in my question.